# get the text of edit box from other program

Tags: vb6

I'm not sure how to get text of edit box from other application using visual basic. In C++ I just find the handle of edit box with FindWindow and FindWindowEx, ... using WIN API. How to do this in visual basic ?

Comment: VB6 != VBA != VB.NET. They are not the same thing, and they are not synonyms for each other. Please use the tag for the actual language you're using instead of just randomly grabbing ones that look alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VB6 just use FindWindow and FindWindowEx... using WIN API.

you'll need the proper declares at the top:

```
 Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

Look at the PInvoke site for the correct syntax for whatever flavor of VB you are using

The real trick is that the V6B controls use to different class names than you might be used to.